# mix phoenix.gen.html with map field type

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using Phoenix with Ecto 2.0. I was positively surprised that I can pass `my_field:map` to the generator and it correctly generates model with map.

It also generated the view and the field is simply string input, which fails validation, because string is not a map.

Is there a format for this string that will be converted to a map?

I am aware that there is no standard way of editing maps with HTML. Just curious if it would be a good idea to parse the string automatically in generated code. This way generator would always produce working solution.

Comment: Why are you using a map type for a string input? The ecto map type will store the exact contents of an elixir map into your database (in the case of postgres it becomes jsonb).

Comment: I generated the all structure: template, view, controller and model with single command `mix phoenix.gen.html ...` and it happens that the generated html has a string input for that field.

Comment: Ahh got it. Might be worth hopping on IRC and pinging one of the contributors to see if there should be an issue open. I would think only the ```mix phoenix.gen.json``` or ```mix phoenix.gen.model``` tasks should accept map type unless templates somehow supported an html json input field or similar. Nice find.

Comment: Or actually just throwing a helpful warning like when you have to still add a route to the router